# Back up and Restore Option inside application

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, icloud

I have an application that stores some user inputs into a Core Data. I want to add a feature which will enable the user to create backup of his data and when required restore the same to his application. Is there any tutorial available ?

Comment: Where you want to store?  Core-data or iCloud ??

Comment: I want to create a back up and store it in iCloud. Is that possible?

Comment: got it..thanks....I have another doubt..is it possible to create a Back up file and export it via email ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this following tutorial for iCloud integration for your backup..

[iCloud Integration Tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/icloud-programming-ios-intro-tutorial/)

You need to create functionality for Backup/Restore as your requirement.

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 2):

Check this [github](https://github.com/irshadpc/CoreData-iCloud-Sync) 
project .

Hope it helps you.